# How to exclude specific duplicates from MySQL group_by dataset?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.7.12. I have a simple query that looks like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count, pic_id
FROM user_pictures 
GROUP BY pic_id
```

I would like to exclude all the duplicate USER_ID records from grouping. So I did the following, however, it's not returning any result:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count, pic_id 
FROM user_pictures 
GROUP BY pic_id 
HAVING count(user_id) = 1
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You want to exclude user that is present more than 1 time in the table, or count them only once?

Comment: @DanielBlais I want the query to exclude the user_id's that are present more than 1 time. So I want to query to count it as 1 but shouldn't count it as 4 if there are 4 of the same values - it should give back 1 still.

Comment: Try `COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)`

Comment: @Barmar Whoa didn't think about that! Nice one, thanks a lot, it's working :) Can you please create an answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` so it doesn't count duplicates of the same `user_id`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count, pic_id 
FROM user_pictures 
GROUP BY pic_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT user_id) = 1
```